# Strange behavior of BlankSequence and Apply

Tags: function-construction

I would like to define a function with BlankSequence. Here is a simplified example.

```
xPlusy[x_, y__]:= x + Plus @@ {y}
```

Now I would like to try `xPlusy[1, #]& @@ {1, 2, 3}`. The result I expected is 7. However, Mathematica returns 2. Why is that?

```
xPlusy[1, #]& @@ {1, 2, 3}; (* MMA returns 2 *)
xPlusy[1, 1, 2, 3]; (* MMA returns 7 *)
```

Comment: Take a look at `{#}& @@ {1,2}` and `{##}& @@ {1,2}`. p.s. `Plus[y]` will do too.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks! `##` is something new to me!